# invalid character error when building a library with the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building an Android Library that includes an already build POCO library. I am seeing this error about invalid character when my library is building. I don't know what the problem is.

```
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libndktest.so
C:/AndroidNative/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.
exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ndktest/WBXMLParser\stringconverter.o:1:9: invalid character

C:/AndroidNative/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.
exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ndktest/WBXMLParser\stringconverter.o:1:9: syntax error, unexpected $end

C:/AndroidNative/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.
exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ndktest/WBXMLParser\stringconverter.o: not an object or archive
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libndktest.so] Error 1
```

This is what my Android.mk looks like.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

### include poco foundation as a prebuilt lib ###

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := poco-foundation-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := ../pocolib/libPocoFoundation.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti exceptions

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

### include poco net as a prebuilt lib ###

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := poco-net-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := ../pocolib/libPocoNet.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti exceptions
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := poco-foundation-prebuilt

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

### include poco util as a prebuilt lib ###

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := poco-util-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := ../pocolib/libPocoUtil.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti exceptions
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := poco-foundation-prebuilt

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

### build ndk lib ###

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-8

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndktest

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../pocolib/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := WBXMLParser\stringconverter.h \
                    WBXMLParser\WBXMLDocument.cpp \
                    WBXMLParser\WBXMLTag.cpp \
                    Classes.cpp \
                    FolderSyncAuth.cpp

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti exceptions
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp .h

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := poco-foundation-prebuilt \
                            poco-net-prebuilt \
                            poco-util-prebuilt

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly specifying `stringconverter.h` as a *source* file?  Should it be pulled in as a result of being included in your .cpp files?

Comment: I can'y explain why it was there. Removing it fixed that issue and now I have this error.
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libndktest.so
/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/tmp/build-16083/build-libc++/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/atomic:662: error: undefined reference to '__atomic_fetch_add_4
'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libndktest.so] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

check your Android.mk 
find if exists " LOCAL_CFLAGS += -flto "
and then delete that 
I resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Stratton noticed, **.h** files should not be listed in LOCAL_SRC_FILES. Also, you need

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -latomic
```